# Celery - Task retry causing weird error

Tags: python, celery

I am trying to retry a task that fails with the following code:

```
@task(bind=True)
def update_listing(self, listing_object, retailer):
    try:
        listing = _update_listing(listing_object, retailer)
    except Exception as exc:
        raise self.retry(exc=exc)
    return listing
```

This is causing the following error to be thrown:

```
Reject: (TypeError('__init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)',), True)
```

I can't what this error relates to, or how I can fix it. Am I calling the retry method in the correct way?

My celery config file looks like so:

```
BROKER_URL = "redis://localhost:6379/0"
CELERY_IMPORTS = ("tasks", )
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "redis://localhost:6379/0"   
CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT = True
```

Edit: Full stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/my-project/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 218, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/my-project/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 398, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/my-project/tasks.py", line 156, in update_listing
    raise self.retry(exc=exc)
  File "/home/my-project/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 666, in retry
    raise Reject(exc, requeue=True)
Reject: (TypeError('__init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)',), True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't decorate instance methods using the `@task` decorator used with regular functios.You will have to use

`from celery.contrib.methods import task`

instead of the regular one:

`from celery import task`

It might have some caveats, as it is experimental since version 3.0, please refer to this link:

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.contrib.methods.html

Comment: I tried using the "app" syntax instead, but I am still experiencing the same problem :(

Comment: What app syntax .. I don't understand ... I say use `from celery.contrib.methods import task` instead of `from celery import task`, or use regular functions instead of methods inside classes.